# How to insert multiple records from Exacttarget microsite to Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, microsites

How to insert multiple  records from Exacttarget microsite to Salesforce ? one record inserting but two records not insering this is iam trying code

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
  Platform.Load("core", "1");


    getFirstToken();
    function getFirstToken()
    {

        //var dd='{"testing505__jobid__c":"7845321","Name":"mani"}'
        var dd='[{"testing505__jobid__c": "234545","Name": "manju"},{"testing505__jobid__c": "2344","Name": "manju"}]'


        var url ="https://atmakurravi-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/testing505__open__c/";

        var payload = dd;
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["OAuth 00D280000014qzw!AQkAQPdpj0qiuy22lBnS0s1LkKH3VKY.9Y33IM2y25KOzkPVk7r6W7SyuPGTy__5hudIKKXNQ0idixB_aVwQ_N4eXTiBbfDp"];
                Write(payload);
        var result = HTTP.Post(url,"application/json",payload,headerNames,headerValues);


    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

The SObject Tree only handles single records and you need to use [this method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm) for multiple records.

However, I'm not sure why you don't simply use the [CreateSalesforceObject AMPscript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) instead, as you won't have to worry about OAuth and Salesforce AMPscript functions won't count towards your API usage limit. You can simply crate something like this:

```
%%[ 
CreateSalesforceObject('testing505__open__c', 2, 'testing505__jobid__c', '234545', 'Name', 'manju')
CreateSalesforceObject('testing505__open__c', 2, 'testing505__jobid__c', '2344', 'Name', 'manju')
]%%
```

You will of course need to call separate `CreateSalesforceObject` functions for each row you want to create, but you can use a [for loop](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_401/) to recursively loop through a rowset and create Salesforce records for each row if you like.